# Quickest way to get user input in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

What's the fastest way for creating user input dialogs ? I could make different activitys everytime I need user input put that looks like overkill in my case.  I just need a small amount of popups in different screens for a user interface.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) from the API. Here is an example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value = input.getText().toString();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

It's a convenient way of retrieving user input.

http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog

Comment: All looks good except **String value = input.getText();** must be changed to **String value = input.getText().toString();**. getText() on EditText give **Editable** object. You need to call **toString()** on it before assigning it to a String reference.

Comment: @AniketThakur Updated the answer, but keeping the old invocation too.